# Modify my Class Mouse Over module to work with all userforms

Tags: excel, vba

Create module a Class of MouseOver event for buttons to use with all userforms

I create a module Class Mouse Over for my buttons and It works on the userform "UF_Valeur".

But I want to add userform as parameter in the Classe1 so that I can use it on all userforms.

My Userfom "UF_Valeur" have 4 controls.

Btn100_00
Btn100_01
Btn101_00
Btn101_01

In Module Classe1

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents dImages As MSForms.Image

Private Sub dImages_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
UF_Valeur.Controls(Left(dImages.Name, 6) & "_00").Visible = False
UF_Valeur.Controls(Left(dImages.Name, 6) & "_01").Visible = True

End Sub
```

In Userform "UF_Valeur"

```
Option Explicit
Dim dArray() As New Classe1

Sub List_Controls()
Dim dImage As Object, Ctrol As control, i As Integer

i = 1

For Each Ctrol In Me.Controls
If Ctrol.Tag = "zero" Then
    Set dImage = Me.Controls(Ctrol.Name)   
    ReDim Preserve dArray(1 To i)
    Set dArray(i).dImages = dImage
    i = i + 1   
End If
Next Ctrol

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
List_Controls
End Sub

Sub Userform_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Dim Ctrol As control
For Each Ctrol In Me.Controls
If Ctrol.Tag = "zero" Then Me.Controls(Ctrol.Name).Visible = True
Next Ctrol

End Sub
```

Comment: Within your class `dImages.Parent` is the UserForm hosting the image control, so you can use that.   Eg. `dImages.Parent.Controls(Left(dImages.Name, 6) & "_00").Visible = False` You haven't really asked any question here though - did you already try modifying your code?  If Yes what did you try and what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your class you have a reference to the Image control, so you can reference the containing form via the control's `Parent` property.

Eg.

```
dImages.Parent.Controls(Left(dImages.Name, 6) & "_00").Visible = False
```